# How do you Find and Replace multiple lines of code using Wildcards?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, replace, wildcard

We have the following lines of code scattered throughout our selenium test framework:

```
{
    {IWebElement}.Clear();
    {IWebElement}.SendKeys({string});
}
```

I have created a method in the base class which does the following:

```
public void ClearFieldAndSendKeys(IWebElement textField, string keysToSend)
{
    textField.Clear();
    textField.SendKeys(keysToSend);
}
```

Manually replacing each instance of the original lines with the new method has too much of a time overhead so I've downloaded a "Multiline Search and Replace tool" which can be found here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.MultilineSearchandReplace

The plan was to execute a Replace All using the Find and Replace tool in the Entire Solution which does something like this:

**Find:**

```
{
    {Wildcard1}.Clear();
    {Wildcard1}.SendKeys({Wildcard2});
}
```

**Replace:**

```
{
    ClearFieldAndSendKeys({Wildcard1}, {Wildcard2});
}
```

However, I have tried this to no success. I have also tried doing it in a 2-step process where only the first Wildcard is getting Found and Replaced but that didn't work either.

Posting on here to see if someone else has managed to successfully accomplish what I am struggling to do.

Comment: Visual Studio allows regular expressions when searching and replacing, so you should be able to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting Greg Burghardt's really helpful answer, I found our solution to be:

**Find:**

```
(.+)\.Clear\(\);[ \t\n\r]+(.+).SendKeys\(([^)]+)\);
```

**Replace:**

```
ClearFieldAndSendKeys($1, $3);
```

Followed by using the Format All Files tool to tidy up the code:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.FormatAllFiles

Answer (score 0):

A [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) search-and-replace can help you with this.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the global search and replace dialog.
2. Choose "Regular expression" in the search options.
3. Enter your regular expression and replace all.

But first, let's use an extension method for `ClearFieldAndSendKeys`, as this will be more idiomatic for C#:

```
static class IWebElementExtensions
{
    internal static void ClearFieldAndSendKeys(this IWebElement textField, string keysToSend)
    {
        textField.Clear();
        textField.SendKeys(keysToSend);
    }
}
```

Now you can call it with `{WildCard1}.ClearFieldAndSendKeys({WildCard2})`.

Which brings us to the regular expression.

You basically want to grab a variable, field or property name, the 'Clear()' method call, then white space, then the same identifer and the argument passed to 'SendKeys':

```
(.+)\.Clear\(\);[ \t\n\r]+(.+).SendKeys\(([^)]+)\);
 1.      2.         3.     4.     5.       6.    7.
```

1. `(.+)` — Any character `.` one or more times `+`. The parenthesis around the `.+` creates a back-reference you can use in your replacement text accessible as `$1`. This should be the field, variable or property for the IWebElement.
2. `\.Clear\(\);` — The rest of the call to the 'Clear()' method. The parenthesis characters are escaped with a `\` so they are treated as literal parenthesis, and do not create a back-reference.
3. `[ \t\n\r]+` — Space characters, tabs, new lines and carriage returns `[ \t\n\r]` one or more times `+`.
4. `(.+)` — Any character `.` one or more times `+`. The parenthesis around the `.+` creates a second back-reference you can use in your replacement text accessible as `$2`.
5. `.SendKeys\(` — The beginning of the call to 'SendKeys(...)' cut short at the opening parenthesis. The next bit captures the arguments sent to 'SendKeys'.
6. `([^)]+)` — A third back-reference capturing the arguments passed to the 'SendKeys' method. This one is a little wonky. The `[^)]` is a character class matching "any character that is **not** a closing parenthesis" since the closing parenthesis is the end of the argument list for the method call. This back reference is accessible in your replacement text as `$3`.
7. `\);` — Just some garbage text to match the end of the method call so your search-and-replace doesn't introduce 1,300 build errors in Visual Studio.

This makes your replacement text:

```
$1.ClearFieldAndSendKeys($3);
```

Regular expressions are worth the time to learn. They are anything but regular, however they are real time savers. Regular expressions are the "Swiss Army Chainsaw" of text processing, and is one of the skills that turn good developers into great ones.